# Insert Multiple row with BeanPropertySqlParameterSource and sequence to generate ID

Tags: spring, oracle, jdbc

I am sure this question must have been asked on the forum before. But I am not able to find it. If you find it a duplicate please redirect me to specific thread.

I am using Spring JDBC with BeanPropertySqlParameterSource to insert records in oracle DB. Before inserting a record, a sequence is called to get value for primary key.

This is how my method looks like

```
public void insertTransaction(InTransaction transaction) {
        Long txnId = getNextId(TXN_SEQUENCE);
        transaction.setTxnId(txnId);
        jdbcTemplate.update(getQuery(TXN_INSERT_QUERY),
                new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(transaction));
}
```

the getQuery method gets the query string from a file, and getNextID method calls NEXTVAL on the sequence.

I need to modify this method so multiple rows can be inserted together. I looked at batchUpdate method but that would require values for each column including Primary Key are populated in all the objects to be inserted in a batch. I am not able to get how do I call the sequence for all rows before call batchUpdate? can anyone please help.

Answer (score 0):

What if you create an array of same size as of bulk upload. Then fill this array by calling seq nextval, and use this astray in batchUpdate.
Or if batchupdate can take a single stay for whole row, then you can create a two dimensional array. Populate it will nextval and query string from file. Then pass it to bulk function. This way you can insert multiple types in single transaction.